# How can I send all the data stored in AWS RDS to elasticsearch(Linux)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash

How can I send all the data stored in AWS RDS to elasticsearch?

I want to save the `data values stored in AWS RDS` to elasticsearch.

my code

```
input {
    jdbc {
        clean_run => true
        jdbc_driver_library => "C:\ElasticSearch\mysql-connector-java-8.0.23\mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://awslink:3306/schema_name"
        jdbc_user => "root"
        jdbc_password => "1234"
        schedule => "* * * * *"
        statement => "select * from schema_name"
    }
}
output{
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "52.188.20.167:9200"
        index => "aws_db_test"
    }
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

**above code execute but error occured.(attempt)**

`error message 1`

> [2021-05-13T14:43:22,484][ERROR][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][main][45d45ca85cb44ad7abd67688adda06f1bd6999bc38e26e71902a47b492a7d6f9] Unable to connect to database. Tried 1 times {:error_message=>"Java::ComMysqlCjJdbcExceptions::CommunicationsException: Communications link failure\n\nThe last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server."}

```
{ 2052 rufus-scheduler intercepted an error:
  2052   job:
  2052     Rufus::Scheduler::CronJob "* * * * *" {}
  2052   error:
  2052     2052
  2052     Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError
  2052     Java::ComMysqlCjJdbcExceptions::CommunicationsException: Communications link failure    
}
```

`error message 2`

> [2021-05-13T14:44:21,425][ERROR][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][main][45d45ca85cb44ad7abd67688adda06f1bd6999bc38e26e71902a47b492a7d6f9] Unable to connect to database. Tried 1 times {:error_message=>"Java::ComMysqlCjJdbcExceptions::CommunicationsException: Communications link failure\n\nThe last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server."}

```
{ 2054 rufus-scheduler intercepted an error:
  2054   job:
  2054     Rufus::Scheduler::CronJob "* * * * *" {}
  2054   error:
  2054     2054
  2054     Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError
  2054     Java::ComMysqlCjJdbcExceptions::CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

I don't know why the error occurs.
help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DatabaseConnectionError`

1. Open database port 3306 on AWS RDS.
2. Run elasticsearch and kibana on Linux.
3. Check the conf file for errors.

> Do the 3 things above and tell me the result.

Comment: I checked the method number 1 and succeeded. Thank you very much.